# Android Google Maps compose how to show multiple InfoWindows at same time

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to display multiple, in this case 2, info windows at the same time.
I am using the Google Maps Compose library.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
GoogleMap(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
    uiSettings = uiSettings,
    properties = properties
) {

  val markerState = rememberMarkerState(position = someLocation)
  markerState.showInfoWindow()
  MarkerInfoWindow(
      state = markerState,
      icon = BitMapUtils.bitmapDescriptor(context, R.drawable.ic_own_position),
      content = {
          Text("Test")
      }
  )

  val markerState2 = rememberMarkerState(position = someLocation2)
  markerState2.showInfoWindow()
  MarkerInfoWindow(
      state = markerState2,
      icon = BitMapUtils.bitmapDescriptor(context, R.drawable.ic_own_position),
      content = {
              Text("Test")
      }
  )

}
```

When I run the app the InfoWindows show and then hide immediately and this keeps on going until the Memory is gone and an OutOfMemory Excpetion is thrown. Also the performance is very bad

I also tried to execute `showInfoWindow()` in a coroutine. This solves the performance issues but then only one InfoWindow is permanently visible.

Is there a way to show both InfoWindows at the same time?